# Can't get text immediately after </span> tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Currently, in my code I break down a larger soup to get all the 'td' tags with this code:

```
floorplans_all = sub_soup.findAll('td', {"data-label":"Rent"})
floorplan_soup = soup(floorplans_all[0].prettify(), "html.parser")
rent_span = floorplan_soup.findAll('span', {"class":"sr-only"})

print(floorplans_all)
```

and end up with the following:

```
<td data-label="Rent" data-selenium-id="Rent_6">
    <span class="sr-only">
      Monthly Rent
     </span>
     $2,335 -
     <span class="sr-only">
      to
     </span>
     $5,269
    </td>
```

Printing rent_span looks like this:

```
  [<span class="sr-only">
  Monthly Rent
 </span>, <span class="sr-only">
  to
 </span>]
```

I can't seem to get "$2,335 -" and "$5,269" from above. I have been trying to walk down the HTML tree, but I'm not able to get the text between the tags.

Comment: may kindly add your python codes

Comment: Please attach the code of what you've tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `td` element has five children:

- A text node containing only whitespace
- A `span` node containing “Monthly Rent”
- A text node containing “$2,335 -”
- A `span` node containing “to”
- A text node containing “$5,269”

You can iterate those children by using the `children` attribute:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

for child in soup.td.children:
    print(repr(child))
```

```
'\n'
<span class="sr-only">
      Monthly Rent
     </span>
'\n     $2,335 -\n     '
<span class="sr-only">
      to
     </span>
'\n     $5,269\n    '
```

If you want to explicitly look for the text nodes, you could search for the `span` nodes and get the next sibling each time:

```
>>> [span.next_sibling.string.strip() for span in soup.td.find_all(class_='sr-only')]
['$2,335 -', '$5,269']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')

row = soup.find('td', {'data-label': "Rent"})
for all in row.find_all('span'):
    print(all.text.strip())
```

an output will be look like this

```
Monthly Rent
$2,335
 $5,269
```

Comment: Your code will only output “Monthly Rent” and ”to” though since the money values are _not_ within span tags.